# Array error when capturing more than 9 words from a string

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, split

I am currently in a Java course and have run into a simple issue. I have tried several things to resolve the issue but no luck. When I give the input:

"5 Hello world and goodbye world"

I have an output:

Hello - 1
world - 2
and - 1
goodbye - 1
world - 2

It counts the occurrences of words but when I go more than 10 words it only displays the first word. I am guessing it is max size limit for the split() or an issue occurring in the for loops. I need it to capture all the words so I can display all the occurrences.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class LabProgram {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String inputString = scnr.nextLine();
      char num = inputString.charAt(0);
      int numWords = num - '0';
      String[] words = new String[numWords];
      int[] occurrences = new int[numWords+1];
      words = inputString.split("\\s");
      
      for (int i=1; i<= numWords; i++) {
         for (int j=1; j<= numWords; j++) {
            if (words[i].equals(words[j])) {
               occurrences[i] += 1;
            }
         }
      }
      for (int a=1; a<=numWords; a++) {
         System.out.println(words[a] + " - " + occurrences[a]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Arrays are 0-based in Java, basically. So if you create an array using `new String[3]` then the valid indexes are 0, 1 and 2. Your loops should be written as `for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++)` etc. (If you're trying to skip the first element, you still need to account for `words[numWords]` being invalid...)

Comment: you also can't go about getting the number of words like this. what does `num = inputString.charAt(0);` equal when the number in the input string is 10 or more? you're still only getting the first character, which would be 1. you might consider looking into `scanner.nextInt();`

Comment: Do you really need to parse the number at the beginning? Why not just go straight to the `.split()` and capture the resulting array? You can skip the first element (which is the number): `String[] words = inputString.split("\\s");` followed by `int[] occurrences = new int[words.length];`. Your outer for loop becomes: `for(int i=1; i< words.length; i++) {`